# How to implement multiple field searching in laravel?

Tags: laravel-5

I have been working on project which have 2 tables posts and description. I need to implement something like multiple field searching, when i select one or more option it should display the result matching those selected option(s). Don't know how to do without bulk of if else conditions. Please help !

`This is my table structure`

posts table 
 id | posttype | featured
description
 id |p_id | region | town 

I have tried with if else coditions, but have to check every posible conditon.

Comment: Can you show your if else block so that we can help you to reduce it?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use [DataTables](https://datatables.net/). It is a lightweight (and free) JavaScript plugin that displays data from your database in a sortable and searchable table via AJAX. The tables are made for multiple search.

There is a [good package](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables) that makes the use of DataTables together with Laravel5 easier.

---

When you don't want to use DataTables, try it with this Eloquent solution:

```
$query = "%{$theValueYouAreSearchingFor}%"
$resultSet = Posts::where('featured', 'like', $query')
           ->orWhereHas('description', function($query) use ($query){
                    $query->where('region', 'like', $query)
                       ->orWhere('town', 'like', $query);
                })
```

Comment: Are there any solution just by using Models?

Comment: @pandesantos Updated my answer

Comment: It throws an error saying call to a member function getBinding () on non object

Comment: @pandesantos Updated my answer again ;) This should be more straightforward

Comment: i need to search by either featured or region or town or any combination of them. When i have where clause like region it should display only posts which have region matching the query. So right now i have where clause region, it is showing the error i mentioned earlier.

Comment: @pandesantos Here we go

Comment: No... it works for single query. I have like drop down search feature to make, for property listing. First thing is that user can search the result by for eg : region, price, type and other query. I have five  dropdown query field and result should be based on single or multiple queries. I searched everything but still havent found any solution.